# eigenvalue perturbation theory for kernel function

Tags: matrix, kernel-trick

Let $S=\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be a set of training examples, and let $K\in \mathbb{S}^n_+$ be the kernel matrix induced by $S$ and some kernel function $k$ (i.e., $K_{ij}=k(x_i,x_j)$). I was wondering how the eigenvalues of $K$ will change if I replace one training example $x_i$ with $x_i'$ (Assume that $K_{ij}$ is upper bounded by $|K_{ij}|\le \kappa$).

More specifically, let $\lambda_i$ be the eigenvalues of $K$, and $\lambda_i'$ be the eigenvalues of perturbation matrix $K'$, $i=1,\dots,n$. I was wondering if we have $|\lambda_i-\lambda_i'|\le C$, where $C$ can be a function of $\kappa$m but not a function of $n$.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?